# Extract RA and DEC values

Tags: excel, text-extraction, degrees

Im using Excel 2010
I am having trouble extracting the correct values from a RA and DEC values.
I want to extract each value from the RA and DEC and place the deg, min, sec in separate columns.

Essentially just rewrite the values in separate columns. I cant do this individually as i have over 3500 items to convert.

Eg.

column A .....| B ...| C .| D

19:24:59.38  |  19  | 24  | 59.38

Here is what i have at the moment.
The RA appears as '7:24:59 PM' in the text bar formatted as time "[h]:mm:ss.s" this appears as 19:24:59.59 in the cell A1.

to get deg:B1 = TEXT(TRUNC(A1,2)*24,"00") --> this produces 19 - correct

to get min:C1 = MID((TRUNC(A1,5)*24-B1)*60,1,2) --> this produces 24 - correct

to get sec:D1 = MID((((TRUNC(A1,5)*24-B1)*60)-C1)*60,1,5) --> this produces 58.46 - wrong. This should be 59.59 (decimal form) or preferably 59.38 (decimal degrees)

Can anyone tell me how to extract the correct values?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `[h]:mm:ss.00` for the format - then it will display the right value.

For B1 you can use `=HOUR(A1)` and for C1 you can use `=MINUTE(A1)` but for D1 you cannot use `=SECOND(A1)` because it truncates the decimal points so use `=MOD(A1*86400,60)` instead.

Perhaps a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4n6vV.png) might help?

Comment: I did as you suggest, the formatting you suggest just adds 00 after the decimal point making 59.59, 59.00.

Comment: Also the MOD() calculations for the second seems to truncate the decimal point just like the SECOND() calculation.

Comment: I have Excel 2010 and I made a spreadsheet with the formulas before I posted the answer.  I don't see how your results would be different from mine but it really did work on my machine.